# Sharepoint WSP Solutions and page URL's

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I’ve been playing about with wsp solutions and a question has occurred to me about how to access an aspx file that is located on the file system from within the sharepoint web application. For instance, here is my visual studio explorer view…

[alt text http://abbeylegal.com/downloads/alp%20solution%20image.jpg](http://abbeylegal.com/downloads/alp%20solution%20image.jpg)

You can see the aspx file I’ve created, when I browse to this file in my sharepoint web application the URL is

http://example.org/alplogin.aspx

What if I wanted this web page to be accessed through a deeper URL…

e.g. http://example.org/adminstration/servererrrors/alplogin.aspx

Would I need to create these dummy folders with my visual studio solution to get a one to one mapping to the deeper sharepoint web application URL I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "module" element in your feature's element manifest should describe this.  Also, if you want your files to be deployed "deeper," you probably want to make sure your feature is scoped as "Web".  Then, activating your feature for a specific SharePoint site will cause your file to be deployed as a page within that site.

The MSDN page called [How to: Provision a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441170.aspx) covers this scenario, I think.

Comment: This has helped and I've got a little further with it, i've explained it a bit better here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926607/sharepoint-features-custom-aspx-pages-at-various-site-levels

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Check your elements.xml file. There you can specify where to deploy the aspx page.